# update displayfor based on editorfor value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

is there a way to update the displayfor value based on the values i enter in an editorfor template? I have created a custom editorfor and displayfor template:

```
@model Models.AddressViewModel

<div class="address">
<div class="row">
    <div class="label">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Street)</div>
    <div class="label">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.HouseNumber)</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="label">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.City)</div>
    <div class="label">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ZipCode)</div>
</div>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing a little at your purpose here, but I am presuming they are on the same page at the same time? If so, you could simply use jQuery to update the values on the fly.

```
@model Models.AddressViewModel

<div class="address">
<div class="row">
    <div class="label label-street">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Street)</div>
    <div class="label label-housenumber">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.HouseNumber)</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="label label-city">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.City)</div>
    <div class="label label-zipcode">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ZipCode)</div>
</div>
```

Then in jQuery something similar to:

```
$("input#zipCode").blur(function(){
    $("div.label-zipcode").text($(this).val());
});
```

Alternatively, if your forms are all Ajax, you could post your editor values to the controller, then in reply return the display view.

Best I can do with the info you gave. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The solution you gave me was almost correct. $("div.label-zipcode").val($(this).val());, had to be $("div.label-zipcode").html($(this).val());

Comment: Ah yes. My bad. Either .text or .html would work. I will update.